# Loading image from server

Tags: android, imageview

I have activity that load's image from server into imageview. Image is displayed after it's fully loaded.

What I want to do is while image is being loaded display it first in low, than medium, and at the end high quality (some images are big). I have no idea how this thing is called and what to google, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you think about using a ScaleAnimation when your image is loaded 100% ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to create the image in progressive qualities from the same stream though some clever technical co-operation from both sides would be nessecary.

Are you grabbing pictures from a server in your control or from other url's?

If you control the server you could query a php script with image quality parameters and get them in succession though personally I think that's a waste of bandwidth.

Why not just indicate the image is loading and put a place holder image, and when the high quality image is downloaded just replace it?

I'm sorry i couldn't help you by telling you how to do it the first way although it's something I may try to implement myself in some spare time.

Comment: There is only one image on server. Basically, all this quality changes should show the loading progress.

Answer (score 3):

Loading an image like this is called **progressive loading**, it is even part of the JPEG standard.

Another possible search term might be [interlacing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlace_%28bitmaps%29).

Answer (score 0):

My finding is that iOS can progressively decode & render Progressive JPEG with NYXImagesKit (see [How do I display a progressive JPEG in an UIImageView while it is being downloaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741486/how-do-i-display-a-progressive-jpeg-in-an-uiimaveview-while-it-is-being-download) ), but Android doesn't seem to have a library like that.