# Image Processing In Ios

Tags: ios, image-processing

I am new to iOS, and I am trying a image on a view. The image in question is large, and fetched from a URL, so to load the view it takes quite some time (almost 5-10 sec).
I don't want to display a place holder and to do some asynchronous call to update the image;
instead, I want image processing similar to how it is implemented in the Facebook iOS app: the big image display hazy at first, slowly becoming the original image as it loads. Does anyone know how this can be achieved in iOS?

Comment: While I appreciate English probably isn't your first language, please try to format the question properly, capitalise new sentences, check spelling etc. It's hard to answer a question that's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 2):

The 'hazy' image you talk about is a 'progressive' jpeg. You can re-format any arbitrary image to a progressive jpeg (on the server side), then use the Image I/O methods to display partial versions. There are a variety of techniques you could use - see [this prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4741486/1633251) for more pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and display a thumbnail image view first or just display a temporary loading image while you are downloading the big image. Take a look at [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for asynchronous image downloading. There are several other frameworks available as well and tons of sample code if you take time to google.

Comment: it is good no doubt, but it really comes down to personal preference