# Does iOS (ImageIO/etc.) support rendering of progressive JPEGs?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, javax.imageio

I'm aware that ImageIO supports incremental rendering of images, but I'm not sure if it supports rendering of progressive JPEGs, specifically, I'd like to be able to render a low fidelity image quickly as it's being downloaded, and eventually arrive at a sharp image.

I've tried sample projects which use ImageIO's incremental rendering - but when pointed at a progressive JPEG file they do not show an image until all the data has been downloaded.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741486/how-do-i-display-a-progressive-jpeg-in-an-uiimaveview-while-it-is-being-download

Comment: also, [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/) also supports progressive download.

Comment: Thanks -- that does work, though it does emit warnings from the console: <Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment.  Perhaps the 2nd example you mentioned, where ImageIO is used directly, avoids the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a small open-source library on top of libjpeg-turbo which allows decoding and displaying progressive JPEGs easily:

```
let imageView = CCBufferedImageView(frame: ...)
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://example.com/yolo.jpg") {
    imageView.load(url)
}
```

see https://github.com/contentful-labs/Concorde