# Displaying interlaced (progressive) Image in ImageView android

Tags: android, image-processing, image-caching, progressive-download

I am trying to display a JPEG image as it downloads like [**this library**](https://github.com/SohailZahidGit/Concorde) but its for IOS is there anything like this in android.

While R&D found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596050/displaying-interlaced-progressive-image-in-uiimageview) but its also for ios.

**1)** Right now i am using [**this way**](https://abdelhady.net/2015/02/14/loading-images-super-fast-like-whatsapp-part-1/) to load it works but the overhead is i have to load twice.

**2)** Also used **fresco** with `.setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)` but didt notice any major change.

Comment: Refer https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1544

Comment: let me know if you r successful at it . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure your jpeg support progressive. [Here's how](http://techslides.com/detecting-progressive-jpeg)

The easiest way to load progressive JPEG is using Fresco. But you need [extra configuration](http://frescolib.org/docs/progressive-jpegs.html) to do this.

Here's the simplest code snippet to load progressive JPEG.

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder
.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse("http://pooyak.com/p/progjpeg/jpegload.cgi?o=1"))
.setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
.build();
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
    .setImageRequest(request)
    .setOldController(imageView.getController())
    .build();
imageView.setController(controller);

// imageView is fresco SimpleDraweeView
```

Good luck!

Comment: @SohailZahid are you sure? I use the exact source code and it works just fine. What's your image url again?

Comment: @aldok , is it possible to implement progressive image rendering like Instagram.to be more clear,quality of the image start out low(blur) and gradually become clearer

Comment: Make sure your jpeg should be decoded as progressive jpeg otherwise it will not work.